# package org.springframework.data.repository does not exist, Spring Boot, Netbeans

Tags: java, spring-boot

He intentado crear una interface y necesito heredar de Spring Boot el data Repository. Pero, al importar el paquete org.springframework.data.repository, me dice que no existe.

Aquí mi código

```
package com.aureoStock.ejemplo1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;


public interface PersonaRepositorio extends Repository<Persona, int>{
}
```

Aquí mi archivo pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.aureoStock</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejemplo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ejemplo1</name>
    <description>CRUD ANGULAR + MYSQL + SPRING BOOT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

También tuve un problema con el paquete javax, pero este lo corregí colocando la dependencia en pom.xml. Pero en este caso, no sé cómo resolver este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo arreglé. En mi archivo pom.xml agregue esta dependencia con la versión 2.4.0, no la 2.4.0-M1 ya que por alguna razón tiene conflictos.

Aquí mi archivo pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 " xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.aureoStock</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejemplo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ejemplo1</name>
    <description>CRUD ANGULAR + MYSQL + SPRING BOOT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version> <!--DEJAR EN ESTA VERSIÓN PARA QUE RECONOZCA LA LIBRERÍA org.springframework.data.repository.Repository-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: En tu pregunta no veo que tuvieses agregada la dependencia `spring-data-jpa`, que es la que lleva los repositorios...